# Why is my question on dd test closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Refer to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/498253/dd-test-indicated-that-it-took-51-second-to-transfer-1-kilobyte-vps-hosting-pro/498260#498260), it is being closed as off-topic

But I don't really know what makes it an off-topic question?

Answer (score 3):

You provide some information about how a dd was extremely slow and then you ask 2 questions neither of which is actually about dd.

> Could my VPS hosting provider be right?

The answer to this question is yes.

> How to deal with hosting provider such as this?

This is off topic/not constructive because we deal with technical issues not contractual.

I believe your question was closed correctly.

Comment: Now if you want to ask a question about what's wrong with your I/O, perhaps we can help. Though as TomTom said, you should check the I/O yourself first...